# Вопрос по PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Здравствуйте. Вопрос следующий:
Установил PHP интерпретатор, установил PHPStorm, в настройках PHPStorm задал нужный мне интерпретатор (картинка ниже). Пытаюсь запустить скрипт php командой run в PHPStorm, открывается браузер, в котором выдается такая ошибка:

```
502 Bad Gateway
PhpStorm 2016.2.1
```

Подскажите, как с этим бороться?

[image]

Comment: Вы пытаетесь настроить PhpStorm для отладки command line PHP?
Немного странно, но PhpStorm имеет свой встроенный сервер, или же вам надо настроить отдельный веб-сервер - XAMPP, OpenServer или другой, и подсоединяться к нему для отладки веб-приложений. Если вы всё же хотите отлаживать скрипт command line, то вам сюда - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Я хотел использовать встроенный PHPStorm сервер для проверки работоспособности моих программ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запуска вы можете использовать встроеный сервер php
в linux это так:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

в директории со скриптами в windows это будет примерно так

```
C:\php\php-cgi.exe -S localhost:8080
```

А вообще смотрите на ошибки в самом phpstorm'е